# Negation of sigmoid function in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

I would like to use the *sets* package for fuzzify and defuzzify in RStudio and, in particular, the negation of the sigmoid function in a *fuzzy_partition* environment.
For instance, this code:

```
weather = fuzzy_partition(varnames = c(bad = 40, ok = 65, perfect = 80),
                        FUN = fuzzy_sigmoid)
```

works perfectly but I would like to have something like:

```
weather = fuzzy_partition(varnames = c(bad = 40, ok = 65, perfect = 80),
                        FUN = 1-fuzzy_sigmoid)
```

that is, the negation of the sigmoid, which does not work.

I am lacking a full manual of this staff, in fact.
Thank you.

Comment: Try `\(...) 1-fuzzy_sigmoid(...)`.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand the full sentence you are recommending.

Comment: The `FUN` parameter most likely expects a function. I suggest turning `1-fuzzy_sigmoid`, which is not a function and should throw an error into a function and show how to do that in my previous comment.

Comment: Right. But fuzzy_partition expects a fuzzy function and *1-fuzzy_sigmoid* seems to not be a valid one.

Comment: You don't understand. `\(...) 1-fuzzy_sigmoid(...)` is a function, `1-fuzzy_sigmoid` is not a function (and throws an error).

Comment: To clarify a bit: `\(...)` is shorthand for `function(...)`, @Roland's suggestion creates a function that passes arguments to the `fuzzy_sigmoid()` function and then subtracts the result from 1.

Comment: `fuzzy_sigmoid(cross = NULL, slope = 0.5, height = 1, chop = 0)` doesn't have an `...` argument, but, the `\(...) 1-fuzzy_sigmoid(...)` construction allows the execution of fuzzy_sigmoid (whose result you don't want) and then `1-fuzzy_sigmoid(...)`. I found it conceptually useful for functions that don't have `...` and wonder the effect on those that do, from the compilers perspecitve, `, ...), ...)` perhaps?

Comment: @Chris I don't understand your comment. Which compiler are you referring to? Have you read https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching? I only suggest `...` because I don't know which and how many arguments the function takes and by using `...` you don't need to know.